# Не понимаю, как работает наследование

Tags: ооп, классы, объекты, наследование, методы

В книге сказано:
[image: В книге сказано:]

Насколько я понимаю, дочерние классы наследуют ещё и поля родительских классов.
Так вот, есть класс родитель:

```
public class Cat {
    int a=5;
    String s="Мяу";
    public void cus(){
        System.out.println("Бегать");
    }
}
```

Есть класс наследник:

```
public class Tiger  extends Cat{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cat tiger = new Tiger();
        tiger.cus();
    }
}
```

Есть класс, который вообще никак не связан с ними:

```
 public class User {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Cat cat = new Cat();
            cat.cus();
        }
    }
```

1)Если дочерние классы наследуют родительские методы и поля, то почему я могу воспользоваться методом cus, только создав объект класса и вызвав метод с помощью его экземпляра?
2) Результат в обоих случаях один и тот же, выводится на экран продукт деятельности метода cus, в чём тогда смысл наследования?

Comment: "только создав объект класса и вызвав метод с помощью его экземпляра" - *But what are your alternatives?* "My cousin Vinny"

Comment: А в чём смысл классов тогда, если нельзя вызывать их методы? О______О  Как вы себе представляете работу с ними?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1)Если дочерние классы наследуют родительские методы и поля, то почему я могу воспользоваться методом cus, только создав объект класса и вызвав метод с помощью его экземпляра?

Дочерние классы наследуют поля и методы (если они не приватные), но суть наследования не запретить использовать методы родителя напрямую во вне (опять же, если только они не приватные или защищенные), а в другом.

> 2) Результат в обоих случаях один и тот же, выводится на экран продукт деятельности метода cus, в чём тогда смысл наследования?

Очевидно описать некую сущность, которая похожа на предка, но имеет отличительные черты и еще какие-то дополнительные фичи.

```
Транспорт -> воздушный -> есть крылья
          -> водный    -> есть водоизмещение
          -> наземный  -> есть колёса
```

В примере выше зачем всегда оперировать предком транспорт и хранить у него и крылья и колёса и водоизмещение и всю кучу всевозможных параметров? Всё это можно разделить на свои типы, которые имеют свою специфику. И вы в какой-то момент времени можете работать именно с конкретной сущностью, которая необходима в данный момент.

Представьте у вас есть сайт продажи любого в мире транспорта, который можно как конструктор собрать из частей. С одним классом вы наплодите всяких `if (transport == 'plane') {}` и условий в зависимости от типа и это будет хаос всевозможных комбинаций из всего что можно. А ведь транспорт не только есть воздушный, водный, наземный. Можно разделить на пассажирский и не пассажирский, грузовой и легковой, боевой и городской.  Авто умеет летать? А плавать? А подлодка умеет летать?